# want to insert timer class time in database as3

Tags: php, actionscript-3

i want to insert timer time in my database.i have created a timer class which is increasing in miniutes and seconds (in a dynamic text field).i have a home_button i want that when i click home_button timer time would be inserted into time column of scoreu table.all code is working fine.column is updating but time is not showing up in database table please help me to solve this..here is my as3 code

```
var myCount:Number = 00;
var seconds:Number = 00;
var minutes:Number = 0;
var myTime:Timer = new Timer(1000,myCount);
myTime.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, startCount);
my_time.text = "";
myTime.start();

function startCount(event:TimerEvent):void
{
     seconds +=1;
 if (seconds > 60) 
 {
  seconds =00;
  minutes +=1;
 } 
 my_time.text = minutes+":"+(seconds >= 10 ? seconds : "0"+seconds);
}
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.time1 = my_time.text;
home_Btn.buttonMode = true;
home_Btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, indexBtn_click1);
function indexBtn_click1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 myTime.stop();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://localhost/timesend.php');
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
request.data = variables;
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(request);
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
loader.load(request);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, dataOnLoad);

}

function dataOnLoad(event:Event) 
  {
    var variables:URLVariables = URLVariables(event.target.data);
    trace(variables.result);    // gives : System Updated
 }
```

here is timesend.php

```
<?php

// data.php

include('connect1.php');

// if we are here, that's mean that we are already connected to mysql server
// and we don't need to do another connection

$etime = $_POST['time1'];


// $link is the same connection created in your connect.php script
if (mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO scoreu (user) VALUES('$etime')")) {

    echo 'result=System Updated';


} else {
    echo 'result=error';
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

there was a problem in table field type declaration ..i declared it as varchar..but now i have fixed the type as TEXT..now it is working perfect..